# Why do Minions need to wear glasses?

Tags: character, despicable-me, despicable-me-2, minions, despicable-me-3

In the *Despicable Me* series and the *Minions* movie, all the Minions are wearing two-eye covering and one-eye covering glasses, depending on the set of eyes they have. See below image.

[image: Image of three minions in joy]

1. Why do they need to wear these glasses all the time?
2. Do these things have any effect on their eyesight?

Comment: Fashion choice?

Comment: Not glasses,. goggles - they're in industrial work clothing, dungarees, boots, gloves & protective goggles.

Comment: @Tetsujin but In secodn film, one of them show sign of low eyesight

Comment: Adding some further reading for Ankit's answer if interested can be found in scifi SE  here. (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43013/why-do-the-minions-always-wear-goggles)

Comment: Prescription safety goggles @AnkitSharma

Comment: @Tetsujin But do zhe goggles do anyzhing?

Comment: And where did they find glasses/goggles in prehistoric times? :-)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From my [own answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/43047/6006) to similar question on sister site:

> In Despicable Me 2, It is shown that minions have bad eye-sight. Without glasses, minion's vision is blurry. When because of, a purple minion, one of the minions lost his goggles, he was not able to see properly. So that appear to be reason behind wearing goggle.

Comment: This would imply *all of them*  have bad eye-sight. I do not know much about minions, but that sounds unlikely to me that every single minion have the same eye-sight issue

Comment: @Ikaros Maybe that's just their natural state, rather than an "issue". Plenty of species have limited eyesight compared to us.  Humans have some of the best vision there is, though it can be apples to oranges comparisons in some cases (mantis shrimp see tons of types of light we can't, but they don't necessarily process it in any where close to the same way). Possibly minion eyes do not normally focus light that well, at least at certain distances, but retain the ability to process higher resolutions when available.  Glasses would then rectify this.

Comment: Also, depending on how they're made (I still think of the *Minions* movie as being fictional in its own universe), it could be a matter of either the original being flawed in that way and thus the clones as well, or that it's because they're mass-produced and therefore not made very well.

Comment: Seems unlikely to me that 99.9% of these "humans" would need goggles to see underwater (which covers 2/3rds of their home planet!) when e.g. fish have no such need.

Comment: You provide no specific citation either here or there. At least point to the relevant passage in a script or link a video.

Answer (score 28):

Minions wear [safety glasses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goggles) because they are engineers.

Comment: This is not a plausible answer. Do engineers wear glasses while sleeping? Surely not! But minions do.

Comment: @Mouvier: Hmmm, it's feature of minions.

Comment: @Mouvier Engineers don't sleep in the lair of a supervillain. The minions don't obey OSHA requirements - that precarious vat of acid could tip over at any time, even while you're asleep!

Comment: _[REAL](https://xkcd.com/378/)_ engineers do.

Comment: @Mouvier Your reasoning would also make the accepted answer implausible, too: you don't need glasses to see while you're sleeping.

Comment: @jpmc26 That's right.

Comment: @Mouvier I was implying that as a children's comedy movie, it doesn't need to be *that* logical.

Comment: @jpmc26 Not sure about that. I have dreams where I have to put my glasses on because vision was too blurry.

Comment: “because they are engineers” Can you cite any source to back the claim that Minions attended university and got an engineering degree?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: You don't need attend a university to be an engineer.

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Minions are factory workers, when they work for Gru, but they are also shown doing other jobs in the Minions movie. “The foundational qualifications of an engineer typically include a 4-year bachelor's degree in an engineering discipline, or in some jurisdictions, a master's degree in an engineering discipline plus 4–6 years of peer-reviewed professional practice (culminating in a project report or thesis) and passage of engineering board examinations.” - Wikipedia

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: You lost main definition: "Engineers, as practitioners of engineering, are people who invent, design, analyse, build and test machines, systems, structures and materials to fulfill objectives and requirements while considering the limitations imposed by practicality, regulation, safety, and cost." - Wikipedia. https://interestingengineering.com/top-8-most-popular-engineers-history. Did Henry Ford attend a university?

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Minions do not "invent, design, analyze" things. They just build them, after Dr. Nefarious has done basically all the intellectual work. BTW good luck practising the engineering profession IRL without having a proper qualification.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto: It's just a movie. It's not real life. Didn't you really know that?

Answer (score 0):

Minions originally mean workers, workers for the Devil. Since the minions are on Earth and are workers, they are shown with a typical workers attire. Dungarees, tools, boots and here, safety glasses. Also the look really cool other than the conventional big round too cute eyes look for animated characters.

Comment: I don't think the Minions in Despicable Me have any relation to the Biblical minions...

Comment: Of course they don't. Except the name.

Comment: I [wasn't able to find that name in the Bible](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/k/kjv/kjv-idx?type=simple&format=Long&q1=minion&restrict=All&size=First+100)...

Comment: A review of dictionary definitions of "minion" did not turn up even one referencing the devil or demons. Any use of the term for devilish supporters is simply an application of the common meaning of "worker" or "assistant", not the origin of that meaning.

Comment: the name is not in the Bible. Although it occurs as a reference when the minions are listed in the satanic bible...according to this page http://weeklyworldnews.com/headlines/15141/13-most-dangerous-demons/

Comment: @Param: That's because minion means "a follower or underling of a powerful person, especially a servile or unimportant one."  And that page lists followers of satan. Similarly, God's followers are God's minions.  The word "minion" has nothing to do with Satan.

Comment: @param The Weekly World News is not a reliable resource.

Comment: @MooingDuck I agree "minion" does not have an origin involving Satan, but the word does have a strongly negative connotation. It's usually associated with serving an evil master, resulting in either the minion being mistreated or the minion being evil themselves. You'd be unlikely to use the term to describe the angels.

Comment: @Headblender Well, not a reliable resource for _facts_.

Comment: @Michael *Minion* is not in KJV. It is in [at least one other version](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2025:40-42&version=VOICE).

Answer (score -1):

I think the glass for protecting their eyes, because minions has no eyelids they can't close their eyes, to protect their they need a super glass